# How to map multiple fields into one destination field using modelmapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

How to map/merge multiple fields into one field? Like concatenate a `firstname` and `lastname` to the destination `fullname`?

```
public class ModelMapperConfigTest {

    @Test
    public void should_validate() {
        new ModelMapperConfig().modelMapper().validate();
    }

    @Data
    public static class Person {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
    }

    @Data
    public static class PersonDto {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String fullname;
    }

    // Test data

    @Test
    public void should_map_multiple_fields_into_one() {

        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

        // TODO: Configure modelmapper to merge the two fields

        // test that all fields are mapped
        modelMapper.validate();

        // test that the age is calculated
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstname("Marilyn");
        person.setLastname("Monroe");
        PersonDto personDto = modelMapper.map(person, PersonDto.class);
        assertEquals(personDto.fullname, "Marilyn Monroe");
    }

    // This method should be used for mapping. In real, this could be a service call
    private String generateFullname(String firstname, String lastname) {
        return firstname + " " + lastname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a `Converter` within a `PropertyMap` for this.

Just configure your mapper like this:

```
@Test
public void should_map_multiple_fields_into_one() {

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

    modelMapper.createTypeMap(Person.class, PersonDto.class)
            .addMappings(
                    new PropertyMap<Person, PersonDto>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void configure() {
                            // define a converter that takes the whole "person"
                            using(ctx -> generateFullname(
                                    ((Person) ctx.getSource()).getFirstname(),
                                    ((Person) ctx.getSource()).getLastname())
                            )
                            // Map the compliete source here
                            .map(source, destination.getFullname());
                        }
                    });

    // test that all fields are mapped
    modelMapper.validate();

    // test that the age is calculated
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstname("Marilyn");
    person.setLastname("Monroe");
    PersonDto personDto = modelMapper.map(person, PersonDto.class);
    assertEquals(personDto.fullname, "Marilyn Monroe");
}

// This method should be used for mapping. In real, this could be a service call
private String generateFullname(String firstname, String lastname) {
    return firstname + " " + lastname;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. All fields, except the one where I want to concatenate my two fields, are null.

Comment: .map(source, destination.getFullname());
here source is 2 . then what can i do?

Comment: .map(source, destination.getFullname());
please provide the complete code for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to use the converter:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

Converter<Dto, Boolean> converter =
    c -> c.getSource().isBoolean1() || c.getSource().isBoolean2();

modelMapper.addMappings(
    mapper -> mapper.using(converter).map(claim-> claim, Dto::setThirdBoolean)
);
```